# How to apply a function to a column in pyspark dataframe using pyspark?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have this in python which I want to convert to pyspark. Below is the python code.

```
import pandas as pd

def mapping_func(df, subject_col):
    return {item:i for i, item in enumerate(df[subject_col].unique())}
    
def func(x, mapping, prefix = None):
    if prefix is not None:
        return str(prefix) + str(mapping[x])
    else:
        return str(mapping[x])

data = {'state': ["Alabama", "California", "Maine", "Ohio", "Arizona", "Montana"]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
        
df1['state_code'] = df1['state'].apply(func, args=(mapping_func(df1, "state"), "S"))

print(df1)
```

Here, I am just assigning state codes to the US states. Then I am applying the function func to assign the codes (with a prefix) to a column which contains US states. This is a fairly simple code in python but I am not able to convert it into pyspark. The output should look like this -
[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXWK6.png)

I tried this -

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
import json

def mapping_func(df, subject_col):
    unique_values = df.select(subject_col).distinct().rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
    mapping = {item: i for i, item in enumerate(unique_values)}
    return json.dumps(mapping)

def func(x, mapping_str, prefix=None):
    mapping = json.loads(mapping_str)
    if prefix is not None:
        return str(prefix) + str(mapping[x])
    else:
        return str(mapping[x])

# Sample data
data = {'state': ["Alabama", "California", "Maine", "Ohio", "Arizona", "Montana"]}
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(data))
df1.show()

mapping = mapping_func(df1, "state")
print(mapping)
df1 = df1.withColumn("state_code", func(df1["state"], mapping, "S"))
df1.show()
```

But this is givingType error - TypeError: unhashable type: 'Column'

Basically, the variable x in function func is a column object and that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of enumerate you can use `monotonically_increasing_id` along with `row_number`. An example code snippet is as below

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pandas as pd

# Initialize SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("State_Prefix").getOrCreate()

def get_state_codes(input_df, prefix=None):
    if prefix is not None:
        output_df = input_df.withColumn('state_code', F.concat(F.lit(prefix), F.col('index')))
    else:
        output_df = input_df.withColumn('state_code', F.col('index'))

    return output_df

data = {'state': ["Alabama", "California", "Maine", "Ohio", "Arizona", "Montana"]}
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(data))

df1 = df1.withColumn(
    "index",
    F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy(F.monotonically_increasing_id()))-1
)
# df1.show()

df1 = get_state_codes(df1, "S")
df1 = df1.drop('index')

df1.show()
```